# Tabulator blanks out "frozen" rows

Tags: tabulator

I have an issue wherein `Tabulator` is blanking rows that are "frozen" using the `row.freeze()` method.  The "frozen" rows are still present in the `Tabulator` table but their contents are not visible.  What makes it even more puzzling is the fact I can utilize the `row.unfreeze()` method to restore the row to its original position in the table with no difficulty.

I attempted to recreate the behavior in jsFiddle but the `row.freeze()` method works perfectly there (ref. https://jsfiddle.net/fkj46sq0/).  This leads me to believe I have something amiss in my `Tabulator` setup but I have yet to discover it.

The following pair of images illustrate the before-and-after behavior I am seeing.

-- Before "freezing the row:

[image]

-- After "freezing" the row:

[image]

As can be seen, the row was "frozen" and moved to the top of the `Tabulator` table.  There is no visible content within this row.  However, I have created a row context menu which includes an "unfreeze" (unmark) method and calling this method will restore the row.

Here's my `Tabulator` setup code:

```
var table = new Tabulator(divId, {
    height: "100%",
    data: [],
    layout: "fitDataFill",
    responsiveLayout: "collapse",
    reactiveData: true, //enable reactive data
    selectable: 1,
    movableRows: true, //enable user movable rows
    cellEdited: function (cell) {
        var row = cell.getRow();
        row.update({ Changed: true });  // Update the data with a new value
    },
    rowContextMenu: myActionContextMenu,
    columns: [
        { title: "ID", field: "Id", visible: false, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center" },
        { title: "Date", field: "DateComp", width: 100, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", sorter: "date", editor: dateEditor, validator: [{ type: noFutureDate }] },
        { title: "Mileage", field: "Mileage", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "input" },
        { title: "Per Diem", field: "Perdiem", responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: true, formatter: "tickCross" },
        { title: "Added", field: "Added", visible: false, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center" },
        { title: "Changed", field: "Changed", visible: false, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center" },
        { title: "MarkedForExclusion", field: "MarkedForExclusion", visible: false, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center" }
    ]
});
table.setData(getDataSync("MileageAndPerDiem", emplId))
```

I've been staring at this (off-and-on) for several days.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The problem stemmed from use of the `Bootstrap text-center` class/method on the `<div>` element containing the `Tabulator` table.

Before:

```
<div id="myTable" class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="font-size:12px;"></div>
```

After:

```
<div id="myTable" class="col-lg-12" style="font-size:12px;"></div>
```

Removing the `Bootstrap text-center` class/method resolved the issue.